# "Simple.OData.Client" Read response headers

Tags: c#, .net, simple.odata.client

Does anyone know how I can use Simple.OData.Client to read the response headers. I need this because our OData endpoint gives specific information back in the form of response headers we need to use in subsequent queries. All methods seem to only give the Response Body but not the Response itself.

Best regards,
Rémy Samulski